# Which is good concept for use section tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to use section tag in my program so which is right way for using section tag for inside of program...

```
<section id="training-pg">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="container">
        // Write you code here.
         <h3>the title</h3>
         <p><?php the_field('training_program'); ?></p>
       </div>
      </div>
    </section>      //  Or 

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <section id="training-pg">
          <h3>the title</h3>
          <p><?php the_field('training_program'); ?></p>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantic way to use `<select>`, according to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp), is:

> A section is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading

And according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section):

> The **HTML `<section>` element** represents a standalone section — which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it — contained within an HTML document. Typically, but not always, sections have a heading.

Seeing as your first example has a section with an ID which clearly defines the purpose of the section, as well as a heading, I would say that this:

```
<section id="training-pg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>the title</h3>
            <p><?php the_field('training_program'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Is the correct and most semantic way to use `<section>`.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is the proper way to use the section tag.

```
<section id="training-pg">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="container">
    // Write you code here.
     <h3>the title</h3>
     <p><?php the_field('training_program'); ?></p>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first way is correct way to use the section tag